# Installing Ubuntu in a data partition in Windows 7

Tags: ubuntu

I would like to install ubuntu along with my already existing windows 7 OS.

[image]

The above image is my current partitions scheme. I have a 40 GB system partition and a 425 GB data partition. I would like to install Ubuntu in the data partition, without losing anything in that partition. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ubuntu instalation disk can do this for you. It has an option to reduce de size of a partition. You can do it beforehand with the same application you were using for the screenshot if you wish. Some detailed instrucctions to do it with the ubuntu installer [here](http://www.easy-ubuntu-linux.com/resize-windows-partition.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But the link you have provided is for resizing the partition in which windows is installed. But what i need is to resize the other partition.

Comment: The installer will show you both, just pick the one you need. From windows you can do it [this way](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/). [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions) may help too.